# How to set the startactivity of tapping the application using monkeyrunner?

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

I am having `.apk` file which is having n no. of screen..

When i tap the app, screen 1 will display.

So, Here my `startActivity` is `package\.screen1` or is there any way to configure the tapping application in the `startActivity`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way I have done to open the app using `startActivity`

```
device.startActivity(component='package/.StartPage ')
```